# MS Access - select one random record for each unique value in a column

Tags: sql, ms-access, random

I have a table of ~3,000 invoices that are from 40 different vendors. In MS Access 2013, how would I randomly pick one record from each of the 40 vendors?

Here is code I've Tried, but like I said it wont differentiate between vendor codes and could give me 40 results from one vendor:

```
SELECT TOP 40 Vendors.Field1, Vendors.Vendor, Vendors.[Lgl Name], Vendors.[Pymnt Amt] INTO [Random Vendors] 
FROM Vendors ORDER BY Rnd(Field1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [Office Support website](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Rnd-Function-503cd2e4-3949-413f-980a-ed8fb35c1d80) it gives a formula: `Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)`.

You could try something like:

```
SELECT Vendors.Field1, 
       Vendors.Vendor, 
       Vendors.[Lgl Name], 
       Vendors.[Pymnt Amt] 
INTO [Random Vendors] 
FROM Vendors 
WHERE Vendors.Field1 IN (Int(3000*Rnd(Field1)))
GROUP BY Vendors.Vendor;
```

This is assuming the Field1 is the invoice number. If that's not the case then you'll have to `JOIN` your invoices table.

Comment: Unless I'm missing somehting, this is just another way to end up where I've been going, perhaps even a more complicated way. I updated my post with code I've attempted, but doesn't do what I need to do.

Comment: If you want one per vendor you'll need to use the `GROUP BY` clause. Also you need some way of distinguishing that you are selecting a random invoice. If you have 3000 invoices, you need to multiply that by the Rnd function. Because Rnd is on a scale from 0 to 1 exclusive.

Comment: I've tried group by, and it ends up returning all 3000 invoices. What is the purpose of multiplying the RND result?

Comment: I've edited my post above. The purpose of multiplying Rnd by 3000 is because Rnd returns a value between 0 and 1 (i.e. 0.7347538). I assume you don't have any decimal values for Field1. That's why it won't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that the table is called `invoices` and you have a table called `vendors`, with one row per vendor:

```
select v.*
       (select top 1 i.invoiceid
        from invoices as i
        where i.vendor = v.vendor
        order by rnd(i.invoiceid)
       ) as random_invoiceid
from vendors as v;
```

If you want details for the invoice, then use this as a subquery:

```
select i.*
from (select v.*
             (select top 1 i.invoiceid
              from invoices as i
              where i.vendor = v.vendor
              order by rnd(i.invoiceid)
             ) as random_invoiceid
      from vendors as v
     ) as vi join
     invoices as i
     on i.invoiceid = vi.random_invoiceid;
```

Comment: Its all one table. The reason is because I need 40 random invoices and picked the vendors first because our system does not allow me to drill down to the invoice level for everyone at once. So I picked 40 vendors and gathered the report for all their invoices for a 6 month period and exported that. The code in my post was how I selected the original 40 vendors. At this point that table has served its purpose and I'm only working off the invoices.